# Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID is not created for new sessions?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jsessionid

======

Just searching for any solution. i was wondering why ***JSESIONID*** was not created after creating a session?

in our application, we are calling **request.getSession()** on a particular servlet. however, this call didnt set JSESSIONID cookie(intermittent) for unknown reason.

Comment: can you share your code ?so that it will be easy to sorted out?

Comment: Only reason could be if in Session manager session tracking was set to url rewriting or SSL ID tracking, which I believe is not set.The other case could be if the `request.logout()` or `session.invalidate()` was called.

Comment: seems to be a configuration issue on clustered webapp setup. the other cluster members doesn't accepting session manager cookies(JSESSIONID) after enable cookies in all custer members, we no longer encounter the issue..

thanks for your help guys.. :)

Comment: @Queen you could probably post that as an answer and accept it. To close out the question. Either that or delete the question if you don't think it will help anyone else out in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a configuration issue on clustered webapp setup. the other cluster members doesn't accepting session manager cookies(JSESSIONID) after enable cookies in all custer members, we no longer encounter the issue.. thanks for your help guys.. :)